# Auth with Android app, but want server to upload data to Fit Store, not Android app

Tags: google-fit, google-fit-sdk

My Android app is used by 1000s of customers. The app sends fitness data from external devices via BLE to a server via endpoint calls. The server runs algorithms on that data, and saves it to a database.

Now I want to send my users' data to Google Fit, but I don't want my Android app to send the data, I want my server to send the data. So the flow would be:

step counting device > BLE > android app > server > database > Fit Store

To accomplish this, I'd like to use the **GoogleApiClient** class to request auth for my users, and upon successful auth, send the auth "credentials" for that user to my server, so the server can upload the user's data on the app's behalf.

Where can I find the "credentials" data from the **GoogleApiClient** object in order to accomplish this goal?

Comment: I would look at using the standard web style authentication flow rather than the GoogleApiClient stuff.  Then the 'credentials' are readily available.  I use this in my Android app and then upload with the rest API's from Android.

Comment: @lfor, I assume you're using a WebView and intercepting the HTTP response to get the token & secret from the body? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes that's the way.  There are tutorials on how to do it if you look a bit.  I Upload only to FIT and already have the flow all setup for 10s of other websites so adding Fit this way just fitted in far easier with my flow than having to add the dependency to Google Play services which I have avoided needing so far.

Comment: I believe we'll follow this documentation: http://developer.android.com/google/auth/http-auth.html